# Is there hardware (like u2f-keys) for passwordless client-side encryption & decryption

Tags: key-management, client-side, end-to-end-encryption

I know that u2f keys are designed as authentication factors, but I think it would not be far fetched to also add a protocol that the user can use to encrypt or decrypt data on the client-side. This would relieve the user from remembering a client-side encryption key and make client-side key management easier, but loosing the key would obviously be quite bad ..

Is something like this included in u2f devices? Is something like this on a roadmap? Are there other key-like devices someone can use for client side key management?

Additionally: Are there any problems with this that I am not aware of besides loosing a key?

Comment: So, like this? https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013790259-Using-Your-YubiKey-with-OpenPGP

Comment: @schroeder Yes, that's what I was looking for !

Comment: I used a single search :https://www.google.com/search?q=yubikey+for+encryption

Comment: @schroeder I was only looking for encryption related to u2f directly, I was not aware that specific vendors would add extra functionality to their devices